Get-ChildItem behaves differently when script is executed from command line and Run WIth PowerShell
I have the following lines in script.ps1:
$CurrentPath = $PSScriptRoot
Write-Host "CurrentPath:" $CurrentPath
$temp = Get-ChildItem -Path $CurrentPath -Recurse -Include bin,obj
Write-Host "temp:" $temp

When I execute the script file from command line:
.\script.ps1

data is printed correctly in console:
$CurrentPath - returns location of the script file
$temp - returns a list of files that satisfy criteria.

However, when I right-click on script file and select Run With PowerShell, then I get the following result:
$CurrentPath - same as before - OK
$temp - empty

Why does Get-ChildItem return nothing in 2nd example?

I would first check to see if it's providing any results from Get-ChildItem, then I would look at the permissions difference. What does Get-ChildItem -Path $CurrentPath -Recurse -Include bin,obj | Tee-Object -Variable temp give you when you call on the ps1?

You are not sharing an actual path example (where most likely the problem lies). Anyways, try: -LiteralPath "$CurrentPath"

@iRon If you are reffering to the path where the script is located, its no spaces, regular english letters: e:\Projects\Production\Components\Blazor\AgGrid\script.ps1. I tried with both -Path and -LiteralPath args, and just -LiteralPath, now temp is not empty anymore,  but it seems that it is not taking -Include into account, so it returns everything located in this folder.

@AbrahamZinala If I run the script from command line, as in my 1st scenario, it gives the same output as the $temp variable (8 folders). However, if I execute ps1 with right-click -> Run With PowerShell, then the window just opens and closes, like it crashes. This behavior is different from behavior described in my 2nd scenario, since then the window does not close, it remains open, and it shows that there are no data stored in $temp (0 folders).

It works for me, although the window disappears pretty fast without a pause at the end.

Does there happen to be a file with the same name (AgGrid) as the folder in the parent directory? Try adding an \*: $CurrentPath\*
